# How do I know if I m loading from the Native Image Cache after compiling with NGEN?

Tags: c#, jit, gac, ngen

I used NGEN to create a Native Image. My understanding is that is it stored in the Native Image Cache (NIC).
When I load my program, I would like to know if it s properly loaded from the NIC and not using the JIT compiler.
How can I know if I m properly loading the image cache? I'm not getting the performance benefit I was expecting so I suspect that I m still using the JIT.

Thanks

Comment: So, to be clear, you're not trying to detect from within the program (which could be bad, having a program deliberately behave differently), but just some external means of checking the running program would be good for you here?

Comment: Closed your question as duplicate assuming that you don't want to do this programatically. If you want to do programatically, drop a comment here.

Comment: How can I do this programatically? Is the following correct?
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
if (assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache)
                MessageBox.Show("Loading from the GAC");
else
                MessageBox.Show("Loading from the NIC");